# How can the MFC Command Button Control display in a Multi-Byte character-set project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I encounter a problem using the “Command button” MFC control in Visual Studio 2010.

When creating a dialog based, non-Unicode, MFC project

[image: Capture of the Wizard]

And when adding Command Button Controls to the initial Dialog

[image: Added Command Button Controls]

When I build and run my Project I get:

[image: My Command Button Controls are invisible]

And when I click on a zone where one of those buttons are supposed to be a checkbox appears:

[image: So my controls are here and react]

Now, I edit the project properties and switch to the Unicode character set:

[image: Project config window]

And when I build and run, Bingo.

[image: My dialog is functional]

My question is: **is there a way it can work in the multi-byte character set**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that are not supported in the multibyte versions of the Common Control DLL.

I had already found out that CEdit::SetCueBanner does not work with multibyte builds, but it seems that all ["Windows Vista Common Controls" require you to build with the Unicode character set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb531404%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

All Windows Common controls and Windows kernel itself are implemented internally as UNICODE. Support for MBCS does exist for backward compatibility. So basically what it does it converts everything from MBCS to UNICODE if you use ASCII/MBCS version of API like `SetWindowTextA()`. The Microsoft is trying to force developers to migrate from MBCS to UNICODE.

To address your question there is no MBCS version of Command button. So you have to switch to UNICODE char set. The time has come.